Не вызывается метод из другого класса, программа завершает работу без ошибок C#
Я пытаюсь написать программу по работе с базой данных из консоли,
и на этапе выбора действия пытаюсь вызвать метод из другого класса,
но при вызове программа даже не заходит в класс а просто завершает работу без каких-либо ошибок
namespace TetsBD
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int modeSelection;

            Console.WriteLine("Выберите режим раборы программы:");
            Console.WriteLine("1.Создание таблицы");
            modeSelection = Console.Read();

            if (modeSelection == 1)
            {
                CreateColections create = new CreateColections();
                create.createColections();

                Console.WriteLine(create.createColections());
            }
        }
    }

    public class CreateColections
    {
        public string createColections()
        {
            string nameColections;
            nameColections = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(nameColections);
            return nameColections;
        }
    }

}


Console.Read(); видимо возвращает код символа. Вы проверяете его на значение 1. Насколько я помню таблицу ASCII, код 32 - это пробел, а всё, что меньше - не печатные спецсимволы. Вот вам дока с примером на побаловаться: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-8.0

Да, @CrazyElf абсолютно прав

Советую использовать Debug (F11)

1 = 49 как верно подмеченно в комментариях, что Read() берет код ASCII
Вместо Read() можно использовать Console.ReadLine() в комбинации с int.TryParse(). ReadLine() считает строку, а TryParse() поможет безопасно конвертировать эту строку в число. В таком случае ваше условие сработает
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out modeSelection) && modeSelection == 1)
{
   //тогда при вводе 1, вы зайдете сюда
}


...Неудобно будет пользоваться. –  rotabor

а можно просто считать с помощью Console.ReadKey() без "ввода" и мы войдем в условие, если мы уверенны, что у нас один символ
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
char modeSelection = keyInfo.KeyChar; 

if (modeSelection == '1') 
{
   //вошли в наш if 
}


А есть разница в нажатии просто единицы или единицы и ввода?

@rotabor, ТС наверняка и ввел "ввод", тк он и позволит продолжить программу, чтоб считать символ, и закончить программу не заходя в if (modeSelection == 1), а тк else там нету, то и "выходит" => а просто завершает работу без каких-либо ошибок // если мы просто введем 1 то ничего не произойдет (?)

Я имею в виду, что в данном случае Console.ReadLine() не  лучшая замена Console.Read(). Неудобно будет пользоваться.

@rotabor, у меня вопрос. Исходя из вашей практики, правильно ли ВСЕГДА ставить else, чтоб к примеру, как в данном примере "обработать" иной случай.

Если есть или может быть иной случай, то конечно нужен else. Это определяется не правилами и практиками, а алгоритмической необходимостью.

@rotabor, вот в данном примере, мы не имеем как бы "алгоритма", что если !=1, но это ведь правильно сообщить как минимум в Log-ах, что пользователь ввел НЕ1...что то такое. Я стала чаще добавлять else, порой как будто совсем много, но так я как будто в курсе, что там происходит, если "тихо" //я ответ изменила, так пойдет? или вы другое имели ввиду?

Как правило, в таких меню если нажал не на ту кнопку, то ничего не происходит. Ну, или можно выдать звонок. Добавление к ответу нормальное.
